# Pros and Cons of Java Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I was looking at some code today and I came across a piece of code using reflection to take a generic object and do different things with it based on the the type. I have never seen anything like this before, and I am wondering what are the pros and cons to using reflection in java?

Comment: Con - It's slow; it can break encapsulation; it's fragile and easily broken; it's difficult to include in code refactoring

Comment: Could you provide example of this?

Comment: Example of what?  Reflection is know to be slow, it's one of the first things you learn when you start using it.  In most cases you use `String` elements to reference methods and fields which means it's fragile and easily broken; it can break encapsulation as it allows you access to private and protected fields and methods of the class, which can make it unstable ... as you're not suppose to have access to them. Don't get me wrong, it has pros, but you need to beware of the cons first ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would say the con is mostly the encapsulation violation, reflection is not that slow anymore, it is obviously slower but the JVM made some improvment that gave a good response time.

Comment: @AxelH Yea, let's break encapsulation 8P - now you have the ability to place the object into unknown state which it was never intended to be in. Do I use reflection, yes, yes I do, have I spend hours debugging it, yes, yes I have :P

Comment: @Mad It's exactly why I place this as a con, not a pro ;) I tried to only use it for some generic limitation. (mostly)

Comment: @AxelH We obviously disagree on that point ;), but to have APIs written well ... because that always happens ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using reflection to take a generic object and do different things with
>   it based on the the type

In general, this is usually a bad idea, for reasons of performance, clarity, and robustness.

It throws away the advantages of a static type system; if you pass in types that the reflection code doesn't handle then you will get runtime errors rather than compile-time errors. If one of the classes changes implementation (e.g. renaming a method) then this will also not be detected at compile time.

If these various types have something in common, then it is usually better to handle this using polymorphism: abstract out the commonality into an interface or abstract class; each subclass can then implement the specific behaviour it needs, without other code needing to poke into the internals using reflection.

If these various types *don't* have anything in common, then why are they being handled together?

Answer (score 6):

There are no pros or cons of reflection in Java. It's a tool which you should use in a specific situation. For example:

- When you create a library which needs runtime manipulation with code.
- When you have compiled jar without source code and author of jar made a mistake and didn't expose proper API.

So basically there is even no question should you use or not use reflection, it's a matter of situation. You should **NOT** use reflection if it possible to do the job without using it in 99.99% of cases.

**UPD**

> Couldn't you use it for everything though? Like if you were a really big jerk you could use it to invoke every method you call, so what is stopping you from just doing that?

Mostly slowness, unmaintainable code, losing of compile time code check, breaking of encapsulation.

Comment: "You should NOT use reflection if it possible to do job without using it in 99.99% cases." I'd even say 100% ...

Comment: Couldn't you use it for everything though? Like if you were a really big jerk you could use it to invoke every method you call, so what is stopping you from just doing that?

Comment: @SageSmith it's a complete mess to do, it takes so much boilerplate code to make it work it's just not worth the effort, also, you suddenly lose a lot support from IDE, as it can no longer tell you the method name or parameters, which is a nice way to say, I'm lazy ;), not to mention is a dog to debug when things go wrong. You should have a very compiling reason to use it

Comment: @SageSmith Nobody stops you. There's no "Reflection Police" that will raid your house. But purposely doing that - I could only imagine the reason to be to annoy co-coders.

Comment: @Divers I up-voted your answer. I think the selected answer had a better explanation though sorry